# Convert to Roman numerals in Ruby

Tags: ruby, roman-numerals

Challenged by [Sandy Metz's newsletter](http://us3.campaign-archive2.com/?u=1090565ccff48ac602d0a84b4&id=24e2bac263&e=9494042f7d), I've tried to implement this [kata from exercism](https://github.com/alxndr/exercism/blob/master/ruby/roman-numerals/roman_numerals_test.rb). However, my solution, which passes the tests, is quite a lot simpler than [Sandy's solution](https://github.com/skmetz/play/blob/master/roman_numerals/roman_numerals_medium.rb). Ok, so she's using refinements and also supports the inverse, but still... As she's probably smarter than me, do I miss something?

```
class Fixnum
  ROMAN = {
    1000 => "M",
    900 => "CM",
    500 => "D",
    400 => "CD",
    100 => "C",
    90 => "XC",
    50 => "L",
    40 => "XL",
    10 => "X",
    9 => "IX",
    5 => "V",
    4 => "IV",
    1 => "I"
  }

  def to_roman
    result = ""
    ROMAN.reduce(self) { |number, (divider, letter)|
      letter_multiplier, remainder = number.divmod(divider)
      result << (letter * letter_multiplier)
      remainder
    }
    result
  end
end
```

Comment: Her solution is over-engineered, imo.  your solution is pretty nice but the way you're using `reduce` isn't idiomatic.  The "initial" value you pass in should be the thing you are building up, in this case the roman string.  the problems is you *also* have a temporary variable -- the "number".  better to define that outside of `reduce`, so you can let the `reduce` expression be the return value.

Comment: True. Initially I had solved it with recursion, but I wanted to get rid of the conditional. But now the `reduce` has a side effect, which is not nice.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3):

I like your solution. You usually see it done with `while`/`for` loops that substract multipliers instead of taking the quotient/remainder. Some notes about your code:

- `ROMAN.reduce(self) { |number, (divider, letter)|`. In a multiline block is idiomatic to use `do`/`end`.
- Prefer building an array + `join` at the end, that appending to a string. Not that it matters with those sizes, but in general it's the recommended way (`+=` in a string is typically O(n^2), `<<` on an array is O(n)).
- `inject` is a functional abstraction. While you can perform in-place updates within the block, it will break the assumption of many readers. One solution is to encapsulate the output within the state (using a hash, for example).

I'd write:

```
class Fixnum
  ROMAN = {...}

  def to_roman
    ROMAN.reduce(number: self, result: []) do |state, (divider, letter)|
      letter_multiplier, remainder = state[:number].divmod(divider)
      new_result = state[:result] + [letter * letter_multiplier]
      {number: remainder, result: new_result}
    end[:result].join
  end
end
```

Note that this is a state machine: it iterates over an input with an initial state, on each loop the state is updated, and the result is the final state.

Comment: Thanks. While you were writing, I already came up with a solution thanks to Jonah's comment, that fixes the last point. Good point about the array + `join` and the hash is also nicer than my array. About the first point: I'm aware of that convention and that it's very popular in the Ruby world, however I like [the Weirich convention](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/07/26/the-procedurefunction-block-convention-in-ruby/) better.

Comment: I knew about that convention (via raganwald). I don't dislike it, but I am afraid it hasn't gotten traction.